# Does silverlight support SQLCE?

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, silverlight-4.0, sql-server-ce

I am trying to create a Silverlight application with WCF RIA service and Entity Framework.
Is there any issue with such a combination?

Comment: ErikEJ is like ... "the Man" for SQL-CE! http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/02/access-local-sql-compact-database-from.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No SQLCE is not implemented for the Silverlight platform.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight doesn't support ADO.NET at all. All data access should be made on the server side, using web services (e.g. WCF RIA Services)

Answer (score -1):

SQL CE is used on the server side, not on the Silverlight side, so no particular issue there.

One problem with Entity Framework and SQL CE is that there is no support for identity columns. You must enter the IDs yourself.

Comment: Can you point to any such article ?As i have tried with one sample app and it failed to retrieve data

Comment: The issue I mention is only when you create new entities in your code. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlce/thread/48984bd4-0921-4637-bd8f-8aa1ae9514ab. If you have a problem when retrieving data, the problem is elsewhere. Does your config file point to the right .sdf file ? Can the EF designer find your tables ?

Comment: Yes and EF model is generated from Sdf file.I tried with sqlserver also and found same 4004 error as .http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/196971/493390.aspx

Comment: I also had this 'not found' error when moving an app to the production server. I had to add the System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.xxx.dll in the Web bin dir, where xxx is EntityFramework, Hosting, Server.